# How exploitable is a machine with a vulnerable library if it is not open to the internet?

Tags: vulnerability, air-gap

Say I have a vulnerable library on a test machine, is it possible for an attacker to use that vulnerability to exploit the system and maybe the network, if the machine is not open to the internet?

Comment: Sure, that's one way that Stuxnet spread.

Comment: "not open to the internet" can mean a lot of things. What do you mean? Is there a way an attacker ***can*** access the machine?

Answer (score 1):

This question is best answered from a [threat modeling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Threat_model) perspective.

First you have to take a look at the interfaces your potential attackers are using. You ruled out access via the internet and you used the tag "air-gap", so I assume no network access in general. This leaves local access to the system like a logged in user or an external medium (e.g. a usb stick) that is inserted into the system and is accessed by the OS.

Next you have to look at the functionality of your vulnerable library. The scenarios depend on your actual situation, so I just give you two possible examples.

1. If the vulnerable library is part of a local tool or service that a local user can interact with - especially if it runs with high privileges like system or root - you are looking at a potential privilege escalation.
2. If the vulnerable library is part of the software that accesses the external medium, a malware exploiting the flaw can potentially run code on the system, depending on the type of vulnerability.

So yes, there are several scenarios including the ones I mentioned above. It depends on the types of attackers you face, their access to the system and what kind of library and vulnerability you are talking about. If you are actually not in an air-gap scenario and have the system exposed on a local network, remote attacks over this networks are also possible, if the library is used directly or even indirectly by a service listening on this network.